# How to find the sumOfelements in array of datatype

Tags: java, arrays, java-8, java-stream

I have a custom class

```
class StackInfo {
    int start, size, capacity;
}
```

and to verify the total number of elements present in an array of such info I have

```
private int numberOfElements(StackInfo[] info) {
    int size = 0;
    for (StackInfo si : info) {
        size += si.size;
    }
    return size;
}
```

I tried converting it using streams to the following:

```
private int numberOfElements(StackInfo[] info) {
    return (int) Arrays.stream(info).map(s -> s.size).count();
    //       ^^ 
    //     to convert long
}
```

But the output for the above code is not correct either after casting as well.

Comment: why not just `info.length`?

Comment: @Kartik I doubt in OP's case that's not what the iterative approach does, its making use of the attribute inside an object instead.

Comment: @nullpointer ooo I see

Answer (score 8):

You seem to be looking for the `sum` operation and not `count` which would need you to convert the Stream to [`IntStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#sum()) mostly. You can update your code to :

```
private int numberOfElementsStream(StackInfo[] info) {
    return Arrays.stream(info)    // Stream<StackInfo>
            .mapToInt(sd -> sd.size)   //IntStream of their size
            .sum();   // sum of all
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `reduce` operation:

```
Arrays.stream(info).reduce((s1, s2) -> s1.size + s2.size);
```

Or the `sum` as @nullpointer has shown :

```
Arrays.stream(info).mapToInt(StackInfo::getSize).sum();
```